# How to find the number of solutions for $|x^2 - 4| = c$, is this just guess work, if so whats the approch?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck on a problem from the precalculus book it's an extra problem not part of the main exercise, but here is the question

Q - if $|x^2 - 4| = c$  find the value of $c$ For which there are $4,3,2,0$, solutions ( this is $\#$ of solutions)  and can there be more, number of solutions $(1)$ if yes, write them down.

How do I approach this?

Comment: May be the graph of $y=\vert x^2-4\vert$ would help you the see it geometrically.

Comment: @Bumblebee one can do that way, but I was looking for a more analytic approach rather than a graphical, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our cases for this solution depend on the value of $c$. The first case would be when $c<0$, one case when $c=0$, one case when $0<c<4$, one case when $c=4$ and so on.

Firstly we note (when $c<0$) there are no solutions as $|x^2-4| \ge 0$ for all $x$. Let's proceed to the next case. So (if $f(x)=x^2-4$ and $g(x)=|f(x)|$) then $f$ has a minimum at $(0, -4)$. Hence $g$ has a local maximum at $(0,4)$. Can you draw the graph of $g(x)$?

It thus follows, if $0=c$ there are $2$ solutions to $|x^2-4|=c$, if $0<c<4$, there would be $4$ solutions to $|x^2-4|=c$, if $c=4$ there would be (why?) $3$ solutions to $|x^2-4|=c$ and lastly, if $c>4$, can you write down (using a graph) the number of solutions to $|x^2-4|=c$?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess knowing the behaviour of absolute value functions and quadratic functions is what it takes to solve this question

Comment: True, if you have a graphing software (like Wolfram Alpha) - then plot this function on it, and maybe a few different ones(?)

Answer (score 0):

> Consider first expressing all the possible solutions in a general form, in terms of $c$. Then analyse the domain w.r.t $c$ for each of the different solutions, such that $x$ is real.

Your equation can have a maximum of $4$ solutions:

$$|x^2 - 4| = c \iff \sqrt{(x^2 - 4)^2} = c \iff (x^2 - 4)^2 = c^2
\\\therefore x^2 - 4 = \pm c \iff x = \pm\sqrt{4\pm c}$$

So we have

$$x = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{4 + c} & c \ge -4
\\-\sqrt{4 + c} & c \ge -4
\\\sqrt{4 - c} & c \le 4
\\-\sqrt{4 - c} & c \le 4
\end{cases}$$

Now, observe for the particular subset of reals, where $c \in (-4, 4)$ all $4$ solutions are real (exist), while unique values such as $c = \pm 4$ takes on double roots; $\sqrt{4 - (4)} = 0 = -\sqrt{4 - (4)}$, hence $3$ possible solutions. For any other $c$, only $2$ solutions are real.